# Update UIPageControl current index of a UIPageController programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a ViewController with a UIPageViewController property:

```
private var pageController: UIPageViewController!
```

The navigation works properly using swipe gesture and the inner UIPageControl is updated correctly.

The problem is that in the first UIViewController, I have a button to skip to last UIViewController. That works correctly but the UIPageControll is not being updated as with swipe gesture.

Here is the code where I perform the navigation to the last UIViewController:

```
@IBAction func pressSkip(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let parent = self.parent as? UIPageViewController {
            parent.setViewControllers([pages[3]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to proper access to the UIPageControl of the UIPageViewController and change the index?

Comment: No, this is the only way to do it

Comment: I mean that I would like to change the index of the UIPageControl when I navigate to the last UIViewController programmatically,

Comment: Oh, then you have to implement dataSource for UIPageViewController. See:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdatasource

`func presentationIndex(for: UIPageViewController) -> Int`
this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I decided to create a UIPageControl and hide the UIPageController inner UIPageControl. So, I could handle the pagecontrol current page without problems:

[image]

I set the pagecontroller childs clear background color in order keep the UIPageControl visible.

```
@IBAction func pressShowMore(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let parent = self.parent as? UIPageViewController {
            parent.setViewControllers([pages[1]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
            parentDelegate?.pageControl.currentPage = 1
        }
    }

    @IBAction func pressSkip(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let parent = self.parent as? UIPageViewController {
            parent.setViewControllers([pages[3]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
            parentDelegate?.pageControl.currentPage = 3
        }
    }
```

And from the first UIViewcontroller I can access parent UIPageControll using delegation.